# How to copy a feature from 1 topology to another?

Tags: topojson

I have two topologies in topjson format and I'm working in d3 on a chloroplethic cartogram.

In file a, I have 7 features (regions) and in file b I have 4 features (regions).

I'd like to get a single feature from file b into file a.

If possible I'd like to do it in javascript. But if not, can I achieve it with the TopoJSON CLI ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the CLI topojson:

```
sudo npm install topojson           # local install via npm, use -g for global install
topojson -p -o output.json -- regions=a.json regions=b.json
```

It *may* works if topojson cli append the 2nd set of data without overwritting. If it works, let us known.

Via Js, get the features with something such:

```
var region_a, region_b;
D3.json(url_a, function(err,json){
  return region_a =  topojson.feature(json, json.objects.yourlayer).features
})
D3.json(url_b, function(err,json){
  return region_b =  topojson.feature(json, json.objects.yourlayer).features
})
var regions = region_a.concate(region_b);
```

I am answering from mobile so i haven't tested these, but pretty sure it's the way to go.